# How to factorise $x^4 - 3x^3 + 2$, so as to compute the limit of a quotient?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Question:

> Find the limit: $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^4 - 3x^3 + 2}{x^3 -5x^2+3x+1}$$

The denominator can be simplified to: $$(x-1)(x^2+x)$$
However, I am unable to factor the numerator in a proper manner (so that $(x-1)$ will cancel out)

I know upon graphing that the limit is $5\over4$. What should I do here?

Note: To be done without the use of L'Hospital Rule

Comment: Do you know L'Hospital?

Comment: Did you try the Euclidean division?

Comment: @Vim Forgot to mention, but we are supposed to do this without the L'Hospital rule.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I attempted the regular division method? Not sure what "euclidean" division is.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane sorry but I just can't see why we have to factorise it, which can be immediately obtained by LHR

Comment: @Gummybears Oh that's too bad

Comment: Your simplication of denominator is incorrect. $x=0$ is not a root of it.

Comment: @drhab Hmmmm.... true that. However, still we should get $x-1$ as a common factor from both the denominator and the numerator, shouldn't we>

Comment: Yes. $x=1$ is a root of numerator and denominator.

Comment: In the future, you know that $1$ is a root, and you can factor out $(x-1)$. Why not try: $(x-1)\cdot (Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D) = x^4 - 3x^2 + 2$ and solve for the proper constants?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the steps
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^4 - 3x^3 + 2}{x^3 -5x^2+3x+1}$$
$$= \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x-1)(x^3- 2x^2-2x-2)}{(x-1)(x^2-4x-1)} $$
$$= \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^3- 2x^2-2x-2}{x^2-4x-1} $$
$$= \frac{1- 2-2-2}{1-4-1} = \frac{1- 6}{1-5}  = \frac{5}{4} $$

Answer (score 7):

You may use [Horner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) here. Since $x=1$ is a root of the nominator (you can check that easily) then you can deduce that down by applying a long division.

Hence your limit is deduced down to:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^4-3x^3+2}{x^3-5x^2+3x+1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{(x-1)\left ( x^3-2x^2-2x-2 \right )}{\left ( x-1 \right )\left ( x^2-4x-1 \right )}=\frac{1-2-2-2}{1-4-1}=5/4$$

Comment: @Tolaso LHR tells me it shoud be $\frac54$ why?

Comment: This is the best solution for someone who does not know many mathematics or for someone who is not very good handling mathematical quantities.

Answer (score 7):

Using the Euclidean division we get

$$\begin{array}\\x^4-3x^3+2&\Bigg|&x-1\\ 
-(x^4-x^3)&\Bigg|&x^3\\
=-2x^3+2&\Bigg|&-2x^2\\
-(-2x^3+2x^2)\\
=-2x^2+2&\Bigg|&-2x\\-(-2x^2+2x)\\=-2x+2&\Bigg|&-2
\end{array}$$

so we find that
$$x^4-3x^3+2=(x-1)(x^3-2x^2-2x-2)$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** The numerator can be factorized as $$x^4-3x^3+2=x^4-1-3(x^3-1)=(x-1)((x^2+1)(x+1)-3(x^2+x+1))$$ and the denominator as $$x^4-5x^2+3x+1\\=x^4-1-(5x^2-3x-2)=(x-1)((x^2+1)(x+1)-(5x+2))$$